# Display elasticsearch query to console

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to display elasticsearch query being executed from repository to console ?

I am using Spring-Data-ElasticSearch

Comment: Are you using dynamic finders provided by `Spring Data Elastic` search like `findByName()`?

Comment: yes...  I am searching like findById()

Comment: I don't think there is any way to display that on console but you can definitely log the queries.

Comment: In logging.yml you can set the log level. And in elasticsearch.yml you can set the time and if time taken by query is greater than specified time,then your query will be logged